# Use same colors in multiple Stackdriver charts

Tags: stackdriver

I have several Stackdriver charts on similar data, but each chart uses it's own color selection. Is there a way to always re-use the same colors for the same data set? So basically sync the color selection between charts.

For example: create a chart on number of pulls on PubSub topics and a second one on the number of acknowledgements on PubSub topics. The charts will not use the same color for the same topic. Can I define Topic1=red, Topic2=blue, ... for both charts?

[image]